# How to get the index of the header in a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

How can i find and get the index of a control in a page, for instace I have a MainBasePage.cs that has a Page_Load and it is used by some master pages as its load code, so for one of the master pages say `mymaster.master`, i need to find the index of the head and then add something after the header NOT IN the header but after `<head></head>` my literal here.

I would really appreciate any pointers.. I have tried doing `Page.Master.Controls.IndexOf(Page.Header)` but no luck

Comment: Why not add a ContentPlaceholder where you want your code and then just inject controls into that?

Comment: That sounds great, problem is.. i am not finding a wayto add the place holder because i cant seem to find the header the index shows as -1.

Comment: What I mean is; change your masterpage(s) to always have a contentplaceholder with a specific name. Then programatically add items to it when you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that it is valid html to put any tags between the head and body tags.

However, if you really want to do that for some reason, you can do this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <%= StringToInsert %>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in the code behind, on page load, you can give it a value.

```
public string StringToInsert;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringToInsert = "<I'm almost certainly invalid HTML!>&nbsp;<I'm almost certainly invalid HTML!>";
}
```

Comment: Blame Bing for that, I am trying to add the Tracking Code and thats where they specifically wanted or needs to be... I am trying to add a concetplaceholder but cant get to find the right way to do it.

Comment: Ignore Bing and put their tracking code directly _before_ the end body tag.  It should work fine there.

Comment: Its not invalid html because its wrapped in a <script></script> thanks though - with the javascript stuff

Comment: No problem - I do want to point out though that the html spec states that a script tag should reside in the head or body tags so I believe it is invalid html even though you're wrapping your script in an html tag.  You might have problems depending on how strict a given browser is when interpreting your html document.  "The SCRIPT element places a script within a document. This element may appear any number of times in the HEAD or BODY of an HTML document." -- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html